# Floating column chart in jaspersoft iReport Designer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to make a floating column chart in jaspersoft Ireport designer as shown in the image below?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a candlestick chart.

Comment: can we reverse the axis in candlestick chart

Comment: Yes. Can you do it in iReport? I'm not sure. But you can customize charts yourself if you are comfortable with Java and JFreeChart.